# Restricting access to page to certain times of the year

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

Is it possible to implement a sortof restriction to my ASP.NET MVC application which will redirect users to a different View when trying to access the View at the restricted times.

I know theres a way of doing this using .htaccess and a simple if/else statement, and I am also aware of URL rediretcing in the WebConfig.cs file, but how exactly can I implement this in my ASP.NET MVC application?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit**
What I have done so far with help from @dekanidze

Attribute (TimeLim.cs)

```
 public class TimeLim : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public TimeLim() { }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            if (DateTime.Now.Date > new DateTime(2021, 3, 1) && DateTime.Now.Date <= new DateTime(2021, 3, 31)
                || DateTime.Now.Date > new DateTime(2021, 10, 1) && DateTime.Now.Date <= new DateTime(2021, 10, 7))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "TimeLim", //input right one
                            action = "PageNotAvailable" //input right one
                        })
                    );
            }
        }
    }
```

TimeLimController

```
public class TimeLimController : Controller
    {
        // GET: TimeLim
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult PageNotAvailable()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View (PageNotAvailable)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PageNotAvailable";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>PageNotAvailable</h1>
       

        <p> Sorry, but this page is not available right now. Please come back 1 March, or 1 October. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating your own custom filter attribute? The code below will be executed before an action method is called.

**UPDATE**: the code is updated according to the OP comments:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public MyCustomAttribute() { }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       
        DateTime dateToCheck1 = new DateTime(2021, 03, 01);
        DateTime dateToCheck2 = new DateTime(2021, 10, 01);

        if ((DateTime.Now.Date > dateToCheck1 && DateTime.Now.Date < dateToCheck1.AddDays(7)) 
            || (DateTime.Now.Date > dateToCheck2 && DateTime.Now.Date < dateToCheck2.AddDays(7)))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new
                    {
                        controller = "Controller",
                        action = "Action"
                    })
                );
        }
    }
}
```

You can apply it on your controller's actions like this:

```
    [MyCustomAttribute]
    public IActionResult Action()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Just to make sure, I create a new attribute in the app_start folder, and then apply this attribute in the main controller with the other attributes, and redirect them to the view I've made? Also, I am not completely sure what you mean with the ```action = "Action"```

Comment: ```DateTime dateToCheck1 = new DateTime(2021, 3, 1);
            DateTime dateToCheck2 = new DateTime(2021, 10, 1);
            TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(7);
            TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(7);
            
            if (DateTime.Now == dateToCheck1
                || DateTime.Now == dateToCheck2)```  This is now what I've got, as you might be able to tell, I want to check whether the user is accessing the page either first weeks of Oct/March, is this the way to go? (Im not sure how to implement the timeSpan's)

Comment: Answering your first question, yes, you apply this attribute to your controller's view. It can be applied along other attributes your view has. In `controller = "Controller"` and `action = "Action"` you need to specify a controller and its' action name you want to redirtect your users. If you want to `check whether the user is accessing the page either first weeks of Oct/March`, I would check if `DateTime.Now.Date > new DateTime(2021, 3, 1) && DateTime.Now.Date <= new DateTime(2021, 3, 7)`. The same applies for October.

Comment: cheers, I made an attribute under a new file 'FilterController', and added the action to the ApplicantController (where all the other actions are). Then I created a 'PageNotAvailable.cshtml' in the Applications views-folder. However, when I simply try to access the PageNotAvailable view, it says that the resource cannot be found..? I am not very sure what to do but I have added what I have done to the question to make it more clear

Comment: Does your `PageNotAvailable` view has its own `HttpGet` action inside the `ApplicantController`? I also would create a separate class for this attribute instead of placing it on top of some `FilterController`.

Comment: yess thats what was missing, the ```HttpGet``` in the HomeController for the page to be available. The only remaining problem now is that I am not sure how to get the dates to actully work, because it does not want to connect..?

Comment: I also tried doing ```[HttpGet][MyCustomAttribute] (code)``` all in the HomeController but this does not work..

Comment: From the code I see that you put the attribute on that action you want your user to be redirected if he tries to access some actions on certain times. Put it on the action that you want to strict the access to.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! it works now. I created a TimeLim class, then a TimeLimController, with a View (PageNotAvailable), and then added the TimeLim attribute to all the controllers. It works:) Do you want me to edit my question so the code is there, then you can copy it into your answer and then Ill accept it?

Comment: Don't know the rules, but since there are comments that everyone can see, leave it as it is and mark it as answered. I'm glad I was able to help you.

Comment: Neither, and thank you so much really helpful:)